# Can i use MAX() without GROUPBY()?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I always thought I need groupby statement after I use any aggregated function. Like for exmaple max() in MSSQL.

But surprisingly if I have to find the second highest salary this query works:

```
select max(Salary)from Employee
      where Salary < (select max(Salary) from Employee);
```

[Source of claim](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20get%20the%20nth%20highest%20salary%20in%20sql&oq=how%20to%20get%20the%20nth%20highest%20salary%20in%20sql&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.5166j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_H1OaXrTmN_qEytMPgv2q2AI60)

Are there any exceptions to this rule that I am not aware of?

Comment: In the absence of a `GROUP BY` clause aggregation occurs over *all* rows returned by the query.

Comment: The inverse is true; in the absence of any aggregating functions, a group by clause is never appropriate. And, when mixing aggregated and non-aggregated values, a group by clause is required (whatever anyone else including the creators of MySQL - tries to tell you)